# Basic Key Off command

Tags: basic

I’m just trying to restart an old program that someone setup, so that I can move forward in the simplest manner.  Basic is so close to Fortran, but Basic hardly has consult anymore:
Here is the start:

```
10 REM CONCRETE COLUMNS
20 KEY OFF:B=30:PI=3.14159:CRSI$=" ":DIM CO(B,2),SB(B),FB(B),IC(24,3)
30 DEF FNWN(Q)=INT(Q+.999):DEF FNAS(Q$)=ASC(Q$+"*"):DEF FNA(Q)=(A=Q OR A=Q+32):DEF FNI(Q)=INT(Q+.5):DEF FNZ0(Q)=Q-(Q=0)*.000001
```

I’m immediately thrown off by the “KEY OFF” followed by variable declarations.  Does anyone on stackoverflow know the meaning of the command?

Comment: What "flavour" of BASIC is this , i.e. what platform or software is it running under?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GW-Basic, the 25th row of the screen shows the first 6 characters of some strings that are assigned to the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F10</kbd>.

<kbd>F1</kbd> is `LIST`
<kbd>F2</kbd> is `RUN`
<kbd>F3</kbd> is `LOAD"`
<kbd>F4</kbd> is `SAVE"`
<kbd>F5</kbd> is `CONT`
...

What the `KEY OFF` statement does, is removing this display from the screen. This way the program can use the 25th row of the screen normally.
There's also `KEY ON` to turn the display back on.

Comment: Q—-?Therefore it’s not necessary.  It does nothing regarding the Dimensioned variables following it.. Thanks for the answer.  I would not have guessed.